# Chinese Visa to visit Beijing to perform a software training course

Tags: visas, china, us-citizens, work, study

I'm a US citizen residing in Florida, USA. I need to request a visa for China to deliver a software training course in Beijing. I'm overwhelmed by the variety of visas and I'm not sure how to get started. My questions are:

1. What visa type do I need (F or Z)?
2. Looks like the Houston consulate is the one assigned to the state of Florida, do I need to be physically present to apply for the visa?
3. If not, do I have to mail my passport at all?

Any other tips or suggestions on how to get the visa will be really appreciated.

Comment: Your first question needs more details to be answered ... are you being sent & paid by a US company or are you being brought in and paid by a Chinese company or are you an independent trainer collecting course fees from your students?

Comment: "If not, do I have to mail my passport at all?" you give your pport to the visa services company - and they take care of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer parts 2 & 3, your passport, visa application and supporting documents must be delivered by hand to the Chinese Embassy or Consulate covering the area you reside it.  You don't have to physically do this, you can have a visa agency handle the physical aspects.

I have used China Visa Service Center ( http://www.mychinavisa.com/ ) in the past for handling my all my Chinese visas (both for tourism and business).  They do a good job, prompt turn around and are quick to answer questions.

They can probably answer part 1 of your question, better than those of us here.

Comment: Just as Tom suggests - in practice for China visas, you almost certainly have to use the "chinese visa service company" in your area.  Just forget about doing it yourself.